# la prudence conseillait à ces dernières qu'ils le fassent

Tags: sens

Please explain "**la prudence conseillait à ces dernières qu'ils le fassent**". It seems to me that "**la prudence**" and "**le fassent**" are contradictory.

> Les garçons croyaient exhiber leur science érotique par des allusions salaces, ils ne savaient que tirer leur coup à l'endroit du corps des filles où **la prudence conseillait à ces dernières qu'ils le fassent**. (*Les Années*, Annie Ernaux, pages 81)

Comment: Why contradictory? *ils* is the subject of *fassent*, not *la prudence*.

Answer (score 3):

You overlook ***où*** in that sentence. Let's say prudence was not advising for the boys to do it but was suggesting a less risky location.

The meaning is more or less:

> The boys thought to demonstrate their knowledge of the erotic through salacious allusions, but all a boy could do was take a shot at the part of a girl's body **where prudence advised her he should** [take it].

The elided action "take it" is what *le* refers to. As a verb phrase it gets the default masculine object pronoun.

(The underlying idea is to avoid pregnancy.)

Comment: J'avais trouvé cette question trop _risquée_ pour répondre hahaha :-)

Comment: Should it be "all a boy could do" or "all they knew how to do"? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterShor The singular vs plural probably doesn't matter (it's a generic) but I would tend to agree it's more about knowledge/experience than permission.

Comment: @jlliagre: I agree the singular vs. plural doesn't matter (although I think it sounds better in English); I suggested the change more because of the knowledge/experience angle.

Comment: @PeterShor Feel free to edit that sentence.